# how to create custom exception with a number in constructor in Java

Tags: java, exception

If I create custom exception with a String message i have: `super(message)` however, i want to have a double number in my exception message. 
The constructor will be something like 
`myException: my message:90.6`. throw exception: throw new myException("my message", 90.6);

Here is the code i've tried but didnt works. Any help would be much appreciate.

```
public class myException extends Exception {

    private String message;

    private double qtyAvail;

    public myException(String message, double qtyAvail){

        super(message);

        this.qtyAvail = qtyAvail;

    }
```

Comment: And why didn't it work?

Comment: You don't need `message` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you do

```
public MyException(String message, double qtyAvail){
    super(message + " " + qtyAvail);
}
```