# Create Exception with a custom constructor in C#

Tags: c#, exception, constructor

I'd like to create a custom exception with a constructor taking some context and building its message itself. In Java, that would look like (see [how to create custom exception with a number in constructor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373081/how-to-create-custom-exception-with-a-number-in-constructor-in-java))

```
public MyException(String message, IContext context){
    super(message + " " + context.someData);
}
```

In C# however, the compiler tells me that base() is not valid in this context.

```
public MyException(IContext context)
{
    base(String.Format("Context is: {0}", context));
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# syntax is:

```
public MyException(IContext context)
    : base(String.Format("Context is: {0}", context))
{
}
```